# Как запустить скрипты в фоне PHP?

Tags: php

После заполнения `html формы`, пользователя перебрасывает на стр `"Спасибо"` на ней запускаются разные функции рассылок, их много, рассылать могут порядка `2-х минут.`
Проблема в том, что после нажатия кнопки `submit` пользователя `НЕ перебрасывает` на стр `"Спасибо"` пока не отработают скрипты.

Можно как-то сразу перебрасывает пользователя на стр "Спасибо" и потом запускать скрипты?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. либо реализовать очередь - Mysql таблица или RabbitMQ, дергать кроном.
2. либо копию скрипта запускать 
   passthru('(php -f '.PATH_DIR.'your_script.php & ) >> /dev/null 2>&1');
   но для этого конечно права должны быть у веб-юзера

Comment: Кажется что RabbitMQ действительно правильный вариант, чем костыли в виде запуска скриптов в фоне с невозможностью нормального контроля выполнения и обработки ошибок.

Можно еще посмотреть в сторону ZeroMQ.